# How to schedule a toast notification for a specific date and time in windows 8 app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I want to schedule toast notification for a specific date and time like 18/3/2015 4:00 PM for windows app in c# for a calender app. I have made 3 combo-boxes (NewEventYear) & so on. What i am trying is..

```
int x = int.Parse(NewEventYear.SelectedItem.ToString());

/* y & z for month and date respectively */

DateTime EventDate = new DateTime(x,y,z);

ScheduledToastNotification scheduledToast = new ScheduledToastNotification(toastXml, EventDate);
```

i am getting an error

> "FormatException was unhandled by user code : Input string was not in
>   correct format"

pointing at

```
int x = int.Parse(NewEventYear.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

Comment: What is the value of `NewEventYear.SelectedItem.ToString()` exactly and what is your `CurrentCulture`? Debug your code and tell us.

Comment: If it is something like `18/3/2015 4:00 PM`, it is clearly not a valid integer.

Comment: You are trying to convert the `SelectedItem` to an integer, this will return full date string, not the year. You need to first cast the SelectedItem to a `DateTime` (assuming that your ComboBox list is full of DateTime objects), and then reference the `Year` property.

Comment: used this code to get culture
var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
it returned "en-US"

added combo-box-item as "2015" from the design view in Visual Studio.

Comment: How to cast the SelecteItem to DateTime ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the help. Solved my problem by writing this code.

```
int x = int.Parse(NewEventYear.SelectedItem.ToString());          
int y = int.Parse(NewEventMonth.SelectedItem.ToString());
int z = int.Parse(NewEventDate.SelectedItem.ToString());
int a = int.Parse(NewEventHour.SelectedItem.ToString());
int b = int.Parse(NewEventMinutes.SelectedItem.ToString()); 

DateTime EventDate = new DateTime(x,y,z,a,b,0)
TimeSpan NotTime = EventDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
DateTime dueTime = DateTime.Now.Add(NotTime);

ScheduledToastNotification scheduledToast = new ScheduledToastNotification(toastXml, dueTime);
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().AddToSchedule(scheduledToast);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you could use is

```
ObservableCollection<DateTime> myDateTimeCollection = new ObservableCollection<DateTime>();
myDateTimeCollection.Add(DateTime.Now); // add more members

myComboBox.ItemsSource = myDateTimeCollection;

DateTime selectedDateTime = (DateTime)myComboBox.SelectedItem; //add this in myComboBox_SelectionChanged event
```